# Date function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

There is a worksheet funtion Date that works like this:

`Date(2016;03;01)`  => 01.03.2016

However, I can't find this function in vba. `Application.WorksheetFunction.Date` does not exists. And simply `Date()` can only be used without arguments to get today's date.

Where do I find the exact version of that worksheet function Date, that takes year, month and day as arguments?

**EDIT:** I *don't* need the current date. I need that function to use with arguments.

Comment: You may need `DateSerial`. Referring to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_date_time.htm

Comment: @newacc2240, Since you were the first, post your answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CDate` can convert String to Date, it supported various input formats. However I suggest checking the string by `IsDate` first.

`DateSerial` can generate a Date by giving Year, Month, Day as integer.

Using `DateSerial` with your example:

```
Dim myDate As Date

myDate = DateSerial(2016, 3, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`CDate` is the closest analogue, although the parsing and locale rules are not guaranteed to be the same as the worksheet function.

If you want the current date then use `Fix(Now)`, or `Date` without the parentheses.

Personally though I'd restrict myself to `DateSerial` which takes a year, month, and day as numerical inputs.

Comment: CDate takes a string as an argument, right? Isn't there a function that takes year, month and day as an argument?

Comment: @Ans, Yes it does take a string. I've added the `Dateserial` function to my answer.